# jquery - index of click element on the list is different on IE 7

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

cms is generating content in this format.

```
<ul id="slide_nav" class="tabs">
<a name="ctn2363_2465" id="ctn2363_2465" class="hidden"></a><li id="button_1"><a class="ohlord" href="javascript: void(0);" id="b1">Bookbag</a></li>
<a name="ctn2363_2466" id="ctn2363_2466" class="hidden"></a><li id="button_2"><a class="ohlord" href="javascript: void(0);" id="b2">help</a></li>
<a name="ctn2363_2467" id="ctn2363_2467" class="hidden"></a><li id="button_3"><a class="ohlord" href="javascript: void(0);" id="b3">Team</a></li>
<a name="ctn2363_2468" id="ctn2363_2468" class="hidden"></a><li id="button_4"><a class="ohlord" href="javascript: void(0);" id="b4">At</a></li>
</ul>
```

To get a correct index of the clicked link I have to do this in IE 7 (use class info in selector)

```
$("#slide_nav li a").click(function(){
   var index = $("#slide_nav li > a.ohlord").index(this);
});
```

On firefox `$("#slide_nav li > a").index(this);` works. On IE this produces incorrect index (0, 2, 4, 6 ..). Is there a way to get the correct index in IE 7 for the above html without using class information in the selector?

My second question is

```
$('#slides img')[index].attr('style', 'display: block;');
```

does not work. I have to `iterate through each $('#slides img') elements` to set the attribute. Isn't HTMLElement object returned from $('#slides img')[index] an jquery object?

Comment: Could you share the solution, ie9 returns indexes as 1,3,5

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To answer your first question, I think the problem is related to the list being badly-formed. The direct children of the UL should be LIs, which should wrap everything else. In your markup, an anchor occurs before each LI - that could be causing IE7 to choke.

```
<a name="ctn2363_2465" id="ctn2363_2465" class="hidden"></a>**<--this is suspect, restructure**<li id="button_1"><a class="ohlord" href="javascript: void(0);" id="b1">Bookbag</a></li>
```

To answer your second question, you can do this:

```
$('#slides img').eq(index).attr('style', 'display: block;');
```

or:

```
$('#slides img:eq(' + index + ')').attr('style', 'display: block;');
```

or:

```
$('#slides img')[index].style.display = 'block;';
```

or:

```
$('#slides img').get(index).style.display = 'block;';
```

The reason for that is`[index]` from your example, which is equivalent to `.get(index)`, gets a DOM element, and not a jQuery object, hence `.attr()` does not work.

As a final point, `.show()` can substitute for `.attr('style', 'display: block;');` and don't forget you can use [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css/) to get or set style properties, e.g. `.css("display", "block");`

Comment: Great answer. Another quick question. How do you dynamically set the selector value, for  example I want to use #slides_1 or #slides_2 as a selector depending on certain condition.
Tried to do this but it does not work.
--
index = 1;
var id = "\'#slides_" + index +"\'"; 
$(id ).attr('style', 'display: block;');

Comment: Try this: `var id = '#slides_' + index; $(id).attr('style', 'display: block;');`, your concatenation looks iffy, there's no need to put extra quotes into the string. `$('#slides_' + index) ` is exactly equivalent to `$(id)`.